# RabbitMQ filtration to specific Users

Tags: websocket, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have an architectural problem.

I know what represents a (fanout, direct, topic, headers) exchange, bindings, queues and almost everything about message architectures. I have the following problem and I need some pieces of advice.

I would like to implement notification logic to my application, where each user will receive in real-time notification only intended for him. ( Actually, I don't want mention what are my UI and BE languages/frameworks, because of an additional level of abstraction) The UI will make a connection to RabbitMQ with WebSocket, SockJS and STOMP. My UI will be only a consumer, the BE is the writer - that one, which will add some Messages to RabbitMQ.

It's perfectly clear to me if I have a direct Exchange with routing key, which uniquely to identify the specific user (for example: my-routing-to-empoyee-with-id-1) and N-number of Queues for each user. This is too heavy to me (I don't know actually whether is normal situation to have so much queues).

**Is there any solution, where I can use only one Queue and the message to be delivered only to user for who is intended ?**

I know a solution, where I can have a topic exchange and to have one writer and many subscribers, but on this way, I can filter the message only on clients level, which is not so secure. :(

Comment: have you considered not using queues at all? Do you actually need to queue those message that UI will receive? I'd go away from a queue and just use some notification store. you UI connects to it and reads messages

Comment: Hi, Alex,
Of course, I will use a short polling mechanism without WebSockets communication and RabbitMQ.This short pooling will work each time when I made some asynch request to my server, but with at least 1 min interval. On this way, I will no keep forever session and from the other side, I will have an optimization check. However, my question above is an interesting topic for me. I'm excited to read some comments and proposals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a very interesting article, which describes me a problem that I have pretty well.

What I want is called **Selective Consumers** and for Enterprise Integration Patterns **this is an anti-pattern** and we should not use it.

For more details, all who want can read this article: https://derickbailey.com/2015/07/22/airport-baggage-claims-selective-consumers-and-rabbitmq-anti-patterns/